# Expanding variables Bash Scripting

Tags: bash, variables, scripting

I have two variables in bash that complete the name of another one, and I want to expand it but don't know how to do it
I have:

```
echo $sala
a
echo $i
10
```

and I want to expand `${a10}` in this form `${$sala$i}` but apparently the `{}` scape the `$` signs.

Comment: What are you doing? Sounds like you need an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways, with different advantages and disadvantages. The safest way is to save the complete parameter name in a single parameter, and then use indirection to expand it:

```
tmp="$sala$i"     # sets $tmp to 'a10'
echo "${!tmp}"    # prints the parameter named by $tmp, namely $a10
```

A slightly simpler way is a command like this:

```
eval echo \${$sala$i}
```

which will run `eval` with the arguments `echo` and `${a10}`, and therefore run `echo ${a10}`. This way is less safe in general — its behavior depends a bit more chaotically on the values of the parameters — but it doesn't require a temporary variable.

Comment: @user1236560: You're welcome! But I see now that a few people have suggested that you use an array, which I think is a good idea: instead of having variables named `$a10`, `$b7`, and so on -- if that's what you have -- you can have an array named `arr` with indices like `'a10'` and `'b7'` and so on. That would let you write simply `"${arr[$sala$i]}"`.

Comment: this wont work because I cannot put something different than numbers in the index of the array

Comment: @user1236560: Yeah, I'm not surprised. Bash only added support for e.g. `${arr[a10]}` in version 4.0, and a lot of machines are still running 3.x versions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `eval`.

```
eval "echo \${$sala$i}"
```

Put the value in another variable.

```
   result=$(eval "echo \${$sala$i}")
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual answer is `eval`:

```
sala=a
i=10
a10=37
eval echo "\$$sala$i"
```

This echoes 37.  You can use `"\${$sala$i}"` if you prefer.

Beware of `eval`, especially if you need to preserve spaces in argument lists.  It is vastly powerful, and vastly confusing.  It will work with old shells as well as Bash, which may or may not be a merit in your eyes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via indirection:

```
$ a10=blah
$ sala=a
$ i=10
$ ref="${sala}${i}"
$ echo $ref
a10
$ echo ${!ref}
blah
```

However, if you have indexes like that... an array might be more appropriate:

```
$ declare -a a
$ i=10
$ a[$i]="test"
$ echo ${a[$i]}
test
```